# android , load a web page that requires post data

Tags: android, post, html

I need to open a web page , in a webview or in browser , but I don't know how to make the request . I have the URL but I also need to send 3 parameters . I have searched a lot but I couldn't find a clear soluion . Can someone help ? And also he HttpClient has been deprecated . What should i use ?

Comment: Does it have to be POST? can't it be GET?

Comment: yes ,unfortunately it can only be POST

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the web page in question does not carry out a CSRF check or a refferer check, the following should work.

1 Create an empty web page and put in in your projects assets/ folder

2 Put a simple HTML form in that page with hidden fields

3 Add jquery to that page

4 Add the Jquery given below to that page

5 Create a webview with javascript and loading pages from assets enabled

6 In your activity on create load that file into your WebView.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form1").submit();
})
```

Comment: You asked a question, I answered. Even with your chrome or IE browser on deskop, you would still need steps 1,2,3,4 and 6 to make it work. The only step you can skip is 5.

Comment: isn't there a faster way ? 
Can't I make something like :
-set URL
-add parameters 
-make request 
-open result in webView or in browser 

This is what i'm trying to do but I can't find the way

Comment: If you insist on using post. The answer is no.